# Windows 7 not turning monitor on after screensaver

Tags: windows-7, cuda

this issue started when I installed Cuda graphics (on installation it asks something about setting it to be the default graphics driver).

Weirdly, every time the screen shuts off (after the delay set in windows power settings) it does not want to go back on. I tried ctrl+alt+canc, moving the mouse, pressing random stuff on the keyboard, nothing, the display doesn’t turn on.

What can I do? Should reverting windows to the last saved state fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the advanced power settings to let you wake the computer from sleep. 
In Device Manager, scroll to the Mouse section, right click it>properties>power management tab> Check "allow the device to wake the computer".
If it still doesn't work, perform a clean boot,uninstall the graphics driver, reboot and try again.